# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Jobeet::slugify()

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, jobeet

I have own project and i would like add for this class same as in Jobeet tutorial:
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05

I copied exactly same as in this article, but i have error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Jobeet::slugify()
```

Any own class for /lib is not included in my actions, but methods getTable, from Doctrine etc working. Not working only my class for all folder /lib. Why? How can i enable this?

Comment: can you paste your class code where you created slugify method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you have this file: [Jobeet.class.php](http://svn.jobeet.org/trunk/lib/Jobeet.class.php) ?

Second, this is strange because by default, classes stored in the following directories in your projects benefit from the autoloading automatically:

- myproject/lib/
- myproject/lib/model
- myproject/apps/frontend/lib/
- myproject/apps/frontend/modules/mymodule/lib

You can force the autoload when you need to load lib from other folders. [Check the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_extending_the_autoloading_feature) for that (this is for sf1.2 but it's work for 1.4).